# Получение вложенных элементов, с помощью метода querySelector(), без использования классов

Tags: javascript, dom

Из элемента добавленного на страницу через *innerHTML* следующим образом:

```js
priceContainer.innerHTML = `
<div class="productPriceTagsContainer">
  <button>+</button>
  <div> 
    Мне нужен этот div
  </div>
</div>
<label class="productPriceLabel">Цена <input /></label>`;
```

нужно получить вложенный `<div>`, с помощью метода *querySelector()*.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.body.innerHTML =
  `<div class="productPriceTagsContainer">
            <button>+</button>
            <div> 
                 Мне нужен этот div
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="productPriceLabel">Цена <input /></label>`;

document.querySelector('div > div').style.color = 'red';
```